# Proving those elliptic matrices in $\operatorname{SL}_2(ℤ)$ are not conjugate

Tags: group-theory, group-actions

Set $\mathbf{\Gamma} = \operatorname{SL}_2(ℤ)$, let $\mathbf{H}$ denote the upper half plane. and let
$$\Gamma_0 (N) = \left\{ \left[\begin{smallmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{smallmatrix}\right] ∈ \mathbf{\Gamma};\; c \equiv 0 \mod N\right\}$$
As known, $\mathbf{\Gamma}$ acts on $\mathbf{H}$ by Möbius transformations , i.e. $\left[\begin{smallmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{smallmatrix}\right]z = \frac{az+b}{cz+d}$.
I know:

- that for any $z ∈ \mathbf{H}$, the isotropy $\mathbf{\Gamma}_z$ is cyclic of order $6$ or $4$,
- that any element in $\mathbf{\Gamma}$ of order $6$ or $4$ is conjugate in $\mathbf{\Gamma}$ to $\left[\begin{smallmatrix} 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 1 \end{smallmatrix}\right]^{\pm 1}$ or $\left[\begin{smallmatrix} 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{smallmatrix}\right]^{\pm 1}$ respectively,
- that any two different elements in $\mathbf{\Gamma}_z$ for $z ∈ \mathbf{H}$ are not conjugate in $\mathbf{\Gamma}$, and
- that any element $\gamma ∈ \mathbf{\Gamma} $of order $6$ or $4$ stabilizes exactly one element $z ∈ \mathbf{H}$, and also $\overline{z} ∈ -\mathbf{H}$.

Using this information, how can I prove that any $\gamma ∈ \Gamma_0(N)_z$ of order $6$ or $4$ cannot be conjugate to $\gamma' = \left[\begin{smallmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 \end{smallmatrix}\right]\, \gamma \,\left[\begin{smallmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 \end{smallmatrix}\right]$ *by some element of $\Gamma_0(N)$*? Please give me only hints if possible.

I know that $\gamma '$ stabilizes $-z$ in $ℂ$ and therefore it stabilizes $\overline{-z}$ as well. I tried several approaches which lead nowhere.

Comment: @vadim123 What’s the problem with unicode?

Comment: Sometimes unicode gives the same result, but in this particular case your gamma-prime did not have any rendered space between the gamma and the prime.  In general, LaTeX performs better when it knows what it's working with rather than some arbitrary character.

Answer (score 1):

First, $N$ is a red herring. What one actually proves is the more general statement that any $\gamma \in \Gamma$ of order 6 or 4 (or 3 for that matter) cannot be conjugate to $\gamma'$ by some element of $\Gamma$.

For me it helps to take a geometric perspective on this problem and not get caught up in matrices. $\mathbf{H}$ is the hyperbolic plane, and its orientation preserving isometry group is $SL(2,\mathbb{R})$. The reason the third bullet point is true is because if $\gamma$ is a finite order isometry of $\mathbf{H}$, or for that matter any elliptic isometry, and if $z \in \mathbf{H}$ is its fixed point, then $\gamma$ rotates around $z$ by some angle $\alpha$, different elements of the isotropy group of $z$ have different rotation angles, and this rotation angle $\alpha$ is invariant under conjugacy by any orientation preserving isometry (element of $SL(2,\mathbb{R})$).

Next, the rotation angles of $\gamma$ about $z$ and about $\bar z$ are of opposite sign and therefore are unequal. This is where the proof uses order 4, or 6 (or 3, but order 2 *does not work*).

Next, the rotation angles of $\gamma$ about $z$ and of $\gamma'$ about $-z$ are equal.

Combining these, the rotation angles of $\gamma$ about $z$ and of $\gamma'$ about $-\bar z$ are unequal, so they are not conjugate in $\Gamma$.

If you like you can translate this geometric proof into more analytic language, using complex derivatives $D_z\gamma$. Thinking of the rotation angle $\alpha$ as an element of $\mathbb{R}/2\pi\mathbb{Z}$, if $z$ is the fixed point of the elliptic isometry $\gamma$ then $D_z\gamma = e^{-i\alpha}$, and then you can check using the chain rule that the derivative of any elliptic isometry at its fixed point is invariant under conjugacy by an element of $SL(2,\mathbb{R})$.

What is proved here shows that even $\Gamma$ itself (and the numbers 4 and 6) are red herrings: for any non-identity elliptic isometry $\gamma \in SL(2,\mathbb{R})$ fixing a point $z \in \mathbf{H}$, as long as the rotation angle of $\gamma$ is not equal to $\pi$ the isometries $\gamma$ and $\gamma'$ are not conjugate to each other by any element of the orientation preserving isometry group $SL(2,\mathbb{R})$ of $\mathbf{H}$.

Answer (score 0):

I think, I got it. Please someone check, if this is correct:

Let $\gamma = \left[\begin{smallmatrix}a & b \\c & d\end{smallmatrix}\right]∈ \Gamma_0(N)$ and $\alpha = \left[\begin{smallmatrix}p & q \\r & t\end{smallmatrix}\right]∈ \Gamma_0(N)$ such that $\alpha \gamma \alpha^{-1} = \gamma'$ and $\gamma ≠ \pm 1$.

If $\gamma$ stabilizes $z ∈ \mathbf{H}$, then $\gamma'$ stabilizes $\overline{-z} ∈ \mathbf{H}$. Therefore, since $\gamma'$ stabilizes $\alpha z$ as well and since there can only be one point in the upper half plane stabilized by some non-trivial action of the modular group, we have $\alpha z = \overline{-z}$, so $\Im (\alpha z) = \Im (\overline{-z}) = \Im (z)$.
Now, the following conclusion is wrong (see my comment):

> This is only possible if $r = 0$ or $\Im (z) = 1$. (You can show that $\Im(\alpha z) ≤ 1/\Im (z)$ for $r ≠ 0$.)

$\Im (z) = 1$ cannot happen: Else, by some translation $\left[\begin{smallmatrix}1 & j \\0 & 1\end{smallmatrix}\right] ∈ \Gamma_0(N)$ the point $z$ would be equivalent to an elliptic point in the fundamental domain of $\mathbf{\Gamma}$ of imaginary part $1$, which can only be $\mathrm{i}$, which is *not* elliptic with respect to $\Gamma_0(N)$, for $\left[\begin{smallmatrix}0 & -1 \\1 & 0\end{smallmatrix}\right] \notin \Gamma_0(N)$.

So $c = 0$ and $\alpha = \pm \left[\begin{smallmatrix}1 & p \\0 & 1\end{smallmatrix}\right]$. Now, it’s easy to check that: $\gamma' = \left[\begin{smallmatrix}a & -b \\-c & d\end{smallmatrix}\right]$ and conjugating $\gamma$ by $\alpha$ doesn’t change the entry $c$ in the lower left corner. So $c = -c = 0$, implying that $\gamma$ has infinite order.

Therefore such a $\gamma$ cannot have order $4$ or $6$.

Comment: Aaaand I found a mistake: $\Im (\alpha z) ≤ 1/\Im (z)$ only implies $\Im (\alpha z) ≠ \Im (z)$ for $\Im (z) > 1$.